# Import File In Python to another File

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7 on Linux

i have two files one is called plot10.py & the other one is called plot10i.py and has def main() in it

with plot10.py being my main file, this is my code:

Comment: Does `plot10i` just include function definitions, or does it also somehow call `main()`? Please [edit] your question to include the contents of `plot10i.py`.

Comment: Is the code in plot10i between the lines `print('Hello')` and `if __name__ == '__main__':` indented? If not, it should be.

Comment: Hi Nick ODell, I think it is otherwise i would have a error by then

Comment: @robotbob33 please check your formatting on your second code block, as it is incorrect currently. In your source code editor, use spaces instead of tabs, then select the whole block, indent it 4 spaces, then copy and paste it into the question's compose box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a module for the first time, it gets executed. So, you need to encapsulate all your execution flow inside functions that will be called from the main program.

In fact, in `plot10i.py` your main is as trivial as useless: just prints hello.

You don't need to use `if __name__ == '__main__'` if you don't have anything to put in. But if you don't and your project is small, you can use that to include some tests. For example, I would add one to things llike `datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')` because they are easy to mess up.

Comment: hi David, i think i managed to solve it only for choice1 when user input 2 or 3 it will get 'plot10i is not defined'

Comment: hi david, i managed to solve it, the plot10i.main() is obsolete so i delete it and the error is gone!